# Detect when 'Remove' is clicked on a file widget form element?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I have a handful of file fields that have the following default Drupal behavior:

- User can upload a file
- User can upload another file in place
- User can remove file

Standard config. Whats happening is the user wants the file being replaced to be *deleted* before the new one is uploaded, and thus, avoiding the issue where files have their names replaced with _N identifiers to ensure unique filenames.

This is because they are referencing physical file paths from the menu and WYSIWYG fields - which means the old replaced file is being referenced instead of the new one. Since these are core file fields and over 100 files have been uploaded, I cannot switch out to a Media field. I'm also not sure if that would even solve the problem at hand, anyway.

Is there any way I can hook into this widget via form alter, detect a click on the upload field, and if a new file is being added, delete the old one in place so that the file being uploaded the name stays intact and thus preserving link targets?

I have looked at the form with both `hook_form_alter` and `hook_field_widget_form_alter` - but I am not really seeing anything I can use to hook into.

Comment: We can rename the file using hook_file_insert(Drupal file FileInterface $file).

Comment: I would add submit handler to the file widget/element that would, after removing usage, physically delete the file.

Comment: hook_file_insert would be too late. Need to delete it when Remove is clicked.

Comment: @Ivan where are you seeing this?

Comment: Be very careful with that approach, if there is any caching in front of your Drupal site (like browsercache, varnish or basically anything that caches static resources) you might get cached results due to same file name.

Comment: Islinet that was the first thing that popped in my head, actually. But we promised to explore if a solution can be done.

Comment: Also it would seem that if you uploaded the same file elsewhere you can overwrite one in the system with the same name unintentionally.

Comment: Reacting to the "Remove" being clicked is to early. If the user does not commit to the action (click save) you have now lost the file.

This does feel like the time for a custom submit handler. Perform the file_copy() yourself and set the $replace parameter to FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. What if the user uploads a new image but then doesn't save the form. The old image is gone but the new one it not there. All permanent actions should only take place after the user has clicked Save.

Comment: Have a look at this module for Drupal 7. https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_replace 

You might be able to see how its done for D7 and then implement in D8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function insights_analyst_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
    if($element['#field_name'] == 'field_figure'){
        $element['#process'][] = 'removeFile';
    }
}

function removeFile(&$element , \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form){
    $element['remove_button']['#submit'][] = 'markupRemove';
    return $element;
}

function markupRemove($form , \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $parents = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#array_parents'];
    $button_key = array_pop($parents);
    //print_r($button_key);
    if($button_key == 'remove_button'){
       //Write your logic here
    }
}
```